# Switch statement loop

Tags: c, switch-statement

can someone tell me why I'm not getting this code to go throughout the for loop and increase the variable i by one through every loop. I only get 'y' printed onto the program software.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1:

        case 2:

        case 3:

        case 4:
            printf("x");
            break;

        case 0:
            printf("y");
            return 0;
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your snippet of code do just after printing `"y"`?

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful/solved your problem, it is custom to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You execute the `return 0` on the first loop in the `case 0:` Is this a typo or do you intend to abort something?

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  switch(i) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      printf("x");
      break;

    case 0:
      printf("y");
      return 0;  //<----- RETURN exits the function call.
      break;           
   }                  
   return 0;     //<-- and if it didn't exit before it will definitely exit here.
}
```

Comment: I want the program to go through the switch several times (until i = 100)

Comment: Then you need to remove both `return` statements. These will exit your function immediately, regardless of the nested loop levels. If this is in the `main()` function, it will also terminate your program.

Answer (score 1):

because it exits on return 0 after it prints the y the first iteration.
It exit the program or function

Answer (score 0):

You should remove return after print statement.

```
printf("y");
>>> return 0;
```